# Cant Install/Boot elementary OS with GPU + AMD PRO WX2100

Tags: boot, amd

I have some problems that happen with an old system based on FX-8350/AMD790 and also with a new one based on Ryzen5 2600/AMD350.

- I can install the system and run it without problems only with my main GPU, an AMD RADEON R9 380X. But when I changed it to an AMD PRO WX2100, the system can't boot.
- When I put installation ISO/UEFI system cant start installation.
- When I try to run advance/repair system go into infinite loop.

---

My 5c:

Problem is, IMHO, in the source of Linux/elementary because I have the same problems with steamOS and it's in the initiation hardware so definitely no drivers issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/7dh5tq/wx_2100_on_linux/) the AMD PRO WX 2100 doesn't work really well under linux at the moment.

Updating your kernel to a more recent version may make it work. [Here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) you can download the necessary packages.

---

If you want to install elementary on UEFI mode you need to set your bios/firmware to UEFI mode and then boot the usb. The key to open the boot menu varies between different motherboards but it's usually F10, F12 or so. If you get into a infinite loop it's because your system didn't detect your bootable USB or you didn't set correctly the first boot device.

Comment: Like I was saying I can install Linux without problems  but only with one GPU so the UEFI/BIOS comment is unnecessary. Im going into infinite loop with the repair option so definitely no USB problem becouse i try to start already installed and fine running system with one GPU .  I try to install new kerner but i have the latest elementary, Ubuntu, Debian and the problems remain simply after adding second GPU system wont start up.

Comment: And important stuff I do not use WX-2100 as display only as calculation accelerator in Blender or in AMD ProRenderer

Comment: To use the GPU as a accelerator you need the drivers as well. Sadly the support isn't good at the moment. Both Ubuntu and Debian use similar versions of the kernel. If you want to use the latest one you need to install it manually or compile it from source. The last version atm is 4.20-rc7.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, Take out WX-2100 from system , install new kernel and then try put the card or first install also drivers (but i'm afraid that when installer do not find WX-2100 in the system do not allow me to install drivers ;(. )

Comment: If you install just the deb files for the kernel then yes. If you compile the kernel from source (not recommended) you need to have the card plugged so the autoconfig detects it.